# Attribute the final output value of a directed graph proportionally to its vertices

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I have a business graph outlining user traffic behavior through an app. The edges are weighted as the amount of traffic it drives into each vertex. The final output vertices have $ values attached to them. How can I attribute backwards the value of each vertex via the proportional weights of the edges?

[Image showing my situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF77s.png)

In the image linked above, the attribution to `Notifications` is simple because that is the input. Input equals output so it would be $1500 after summing up all of the infinite paths.

Please consider the `Notification Center` though. How can I calculate the proportion of the total $1500 in purchases that can be attributed to all paths containing it? There could be an infinite number of paths since a user theoretically could jump infinitely between vertices before their purchase. Is their a formula I can use for this? Thanks.